# How to split text in column into 2 columns (MYSQL) after separator

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for some code, which can do separated text from column description into columns test 1 and test 2

Example

**description** (price $250, New York, Beautiful house)

What I need

**test 1**
$250

**test2**
New York

Comment: This isn't a place to come for free labor.  Show us what you've tried and we'll help you figure out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for the `explode()` function.